# Crear medida que muestre el acumulado de una expresion para un periodo de 3 meses incluyendo el mes en curso en Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, data, datos, visualización-de-datos, dax

Hola Tengo un grafico de barras que me muestra el valor de una medida en un periodo de 13 meses, de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero Lograr es que me muestre el acumulado de los ultimos 3 meses en cada mes, es decir que sea algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde si se fijan, el valor de el mes de noviembre es la suma de los valores del mes de septiembre, octubre y noviembre, lo mismo con el valor de octubre, que es la suma de, agosto, septiembre y octubre y asi suscesivamente con cada mes.

les dejo el codigo DAX de la medida que se muestra en el primer grafico a ver si me pueden ayudar a entender como modificarla para optener lo que necesito:

```
Satisfaccion 13 M =  CALCULATE([Satisfacción], all('dim Date'), DATESINPERIOD('dim Date'[Date], SELECTEDVALUE('dim Date'[Date]), 13 , MONTH))


Satisfacción = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Encuestas[SATISFACCION_VA]))
```

Comment: Satisfaccion 13 M =  CALCULATE([Satisfacción], all('dim Date'), DATESINPERIOD('dim Date'[Date], SELECTEDVALUE('dim Date'[Date]), -13 , MONTH)),

En el codigo anterior fijense que no es 13 como segundo parametro del DATESINPERIOD sino - 13

Comment: ¿Y no te sirve una como la que tienes, pero con 3 meses?
`Satisfaccion 3 M =  CALCULATE([Satisfacción], all('dim Date'), DATESINPERIOD('dim Date'[Date], SELECTEDVALUE('dim Date'[Date]), -3 , MONTH))`